# How to implement "show more" in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I want to display a certain number of records from the database on the page. However, when I click the "show more" button, it displays all the records.

```
@foreach ($spec as $item)
    @continue($item->id == 1)
    {{ $item->title }}
    <div class="spec__item-lang">
        {{ $item->lang }}
    </div>
    @break($item->id == 7)
@endforeach
<button class="spec__btn">See more</button>
```

---

```
public function index()
{
    $spec = Qualifications::simplePaginate(6);

    return view('spec', compact('spec'));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom pagination. And

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
  if($request->has('type'){
     if($request->type=='all'){
          $spec = Qualifications::all(6);
     }
   }else{
          $spec = Qualifications::simplePaginate(6);
     }
  return view('spec', compact('spec'));
}
```

Comment: what to write in blade.php

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).